# Проблема с кодировкой в BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.x, utf-8, beautiful-soup, кириллица

При попытке распарсить страницу с кодировкой windows-1251, получаю текст вот в такой кодировке (Â ñîòåéíèêå èëè êàñòðþëå)

```
htmlString = get(url).text
html = BeautifulSoup(htmlString, 'html5lib')
tags = html.find_all('div', {'class': 'story'})
text = [t.get_text() for t in tags]
print text[0]
```

Загуглил решение:

```
a.text = text[0].encode('latin1').decode('cp1251')
```

Однако на некоторых символах страницах валится:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode character u'\u25cf' in position 25: ordinal not in range(256)
```

Менял latin1 на utf8, но не помогло.

Comment: «Менял latin1 на utf8, но не помогло.» — а вот это уже явно непонимание принципа работы строк в питоне. Тем не менее, какая версия питона, какая версия BeautifulSoup?

Comment: А вообще телепатия подсказывает, что проблема вообще в методе `get`, в связи с чем требуется узнать этот самый url.

Comment: @andreymal судя по `print text[0]`, версия python 2.x

Comment: И правда, проглядел чего-то

Comment: @andreymal
Версия python - 2. 
beautifulsoup4. 
url - all-forcooking.com/vtorye-blyuda/1882-grechnevye-oladi.html
{'class': 'fstory'}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У вас проблема с кодировкой в requests, а не в BeautifulSoup.

```
req = get(url)
req.encoding = 'cp1251'
htmlString = req.text
```

Ну и так далее.